# How to get the year of a date, depending on the weeknumber

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, date

I know how to get the year out of a date. But how can I get the year of a date, depending on the week number of that date?

Example: 28-12-2015 has week number 1 (ISO_WEEK). In this case, the week number does not belong to 2015, but 2016. Also: 1-1-2016: Weeknumber 53, so 1-1-2016 does not belong to 2016, but to 2015.

Is there a function to do this easily in SQL?

No there isn't, but I created it myself.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ISO_YEAR](@date DATETIME)
returns SMALLINT
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @ISO_YEAR SMALLINT = CASE
         WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, @date)=1
             AND MONTH(@date)=12 THEN YEAR(@date)+1
         WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, @date)=53
             AND MONTH(@date)=1 THEN YEAR(@date)-1
         WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, @date)=52
             AND Month(@date)=1 THEN YEAR(@date)-1             
         ELSE YEAR(@date)
        END;
     RETURN @ISO_YEAR;
END;
```

Comment: declare @date datetime = '12/28/2015'
Select WeekNo = datepart(wk,@date), [Year] = year(@date)

Answer (score 0):

As per your question it seems you have two different dates and you are not able to identify in which year this date belongs to.

I have a small example here:

```
DECLARE @Date datetime, @Date1 datetime 
  SET @Date = '2015-12-28' 
  SET @Date1 = '2016-01-01' 


  SELECT CASE WHEN datepart(Wk , @Date ) < datepart(Wk , @Date1 ) THEN  (datepart(YEAR , @Date1 ) + 1)  ELSE (datepart(YEAR , @Date1 )) END AS GETYEAR
```

OUTPUT: 
2016

I storngly recommend that this is not a correct way to know the year. it is not a +/- 1 logic here. there are max 53 weeks every year and you should always get the year from date which you have.

refer fiddle: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/4510

Comment: It's not about two different dates, it's about 1 date. I only gave 2 examples.